# How do I have a headless machine share its wireless connection through ethernet?

Tags: networking, nfs

I'm finding a lot of information on how to do this using a GUI. Here is my current setup:

-Network shared through wireless router
-Computer has wireless connection
-Want computer to share this wireless connection over ethernet while also being able to share NFS

How would I go about doing this? I'm at my wit's end!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a whole article that demonstrates several different methods, including CLI only ones, to set up internet connection sharing.  Hope this helps, :-)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: It looks like it'll work!!! I'll give it a shot, and I'll let you know if it works. Thanks! ...I need to start reading the documentation, huh? :)